# PHP problems with scandir function

Tags: php, filepath, dynamic-arrays, scandir

dirdel.php:

```
<?php
//The name of the folder.
$dir = 'images';
//Get a list of all of the file names in the folder.
$arraydir = scandir($dir, 2);
print_r($arraydir);

//Loop through the file list.
foreach ($arraydir as $key => $value) { 
unlink($arraydir[2]); 
}  
?>
```

Array outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => . 
        [1] => .. 
        [2] => ana.png 
        [3] => ban.png 
        [4] => ing.png 
        [5] => maca.png 
        [6] => no.png 
        [7] => pret.png )
```

> Warning: unlink(ana.png): No such file or directory in C:\phpdesktop- 
>       chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\dirdel.php on line 10

To investigate the error, I also tried something like:

```
require 'images/';
```

Output:

> Warning: require(C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\images): 
>    failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc- 
>    php-7.1.3\www\dirdel.php on line 2

I want to delete the file "ana.png" represented by: "$arraydir[2]" (the file is found in www/images)

I already searched in several places, but I did not find anything, that help me to fix this problem.

Is there any solution for this?

Alternatives are valid, as long as they respect the structure of the arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => . 
        [1] => .. 
        [2] => ana.png 
        [3] => ban.png 
        [4] => ing.png 
        [5] => maca.png 
        [6] => no.png 
        [7] => pret.png )
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: you unlink an incorrect path you just specify the whole path not just the file name

Comment: Can you clarify what you wanted to achieve using `require 'images/'`? `require` is used to include some more PHP code, not to set a directory context

Comment: Not sure if the `foreach` is needed.  You may also need to exclude the `.` and `..` directories if you are going to use a `foreach`.

Comment: Your code is very dangerous because you don't ignore "." or "..".  If your code actually worked the first thing it would do is attempt to delete the directory being scanned.  The second thing it would do is attempt to delete that directory's parent directory.

Comment: @GordonM Well no, as OP only ever deletes `$arraydir[2]` which I will admit is also rather dangerous, but not quite what you suggest

Comment: @GordonM Thanks for your reply, actually this script is part of another page, so it will only run once time for each time a specific condition is satisfied.

(This code is a complement, for an custom RSS feed, nothing important information's.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you run your code you'll always unlink only index 2 of your array. You have to make use of the variables and references that you are using in your foreach loop. I suggest you try the below mentioned code:

```
<?php
    //The name of the folder.
    $dir = 'images';

    //Get a list of all of the file names in the folder.
    $arraydir = scandir($dir, 2);
    print_r($arraydir);

    //Loop through the file list.
    foreach ($arraydir as $key => $value) {
        if ($arraydir[$key] == 'ana.png' && file_exists($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arraydir[$key])) {
            unlink($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $arraydir[$key]);
            break;
        } 
    }  
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You make a good point, but this will delete all files in the directory wont it? Not just `ana.png`

Comment: @RiggsFolly After setting the value "2" to "$ arraydir [$ key]" -> to "$ arraydir [2]" it deletes the correct file.

Comment: Yes. But you'll delete the same file over and over again. This leads to un-necessary run time. If you want to delete only "ana.png" then you can use `$ arraydir[2]` but please put a break statement after that. I was giving you an example of the general sense. I have edited my code for your solution.

Comment: Well, this code will be called by another page when a condition is satisfied, it will erase the image only once time, avoiding other problems.

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 3):

The file is in the `images` folder but you do not add that to the `unlink()` function parameter.

So try this instead

```
unlink($dir . '/' . $arraydir[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for fix the topic and for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

When you first tried to  delete the file ana.png, the path used was relative to your current directory, so the file was not found. What resulted in the first error.

To solve that, you should either give an absolute path name ,

```
$prefix = 'C:\\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\\www\images\\';
$filename = $prefix . $arraydir[2];
unlink($filename)
```

or, concatenate your file name with its directory name `$dir . '/' . $arraydir[2]`

```
$dir = 'images'; /*Assuming your current directory is 'C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\'*/
unlink($dir . $arraydir[2]);
```

As for the second error, it seems that you don't have write permissions on the folder 'C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\images'; you should change the files and directory permissions. I would suggest following this [tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXrYaysbXeAhWCJ8AKHbb0CBgQFjARegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.windowscentral.com%2Fhow-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10&usg=AOvVaw3aJyUWFERvigrGpNNKhnx5) about setting about file permissions on windows 10

Comment: The problem has been solved, but thanks for showing us another alternative!

and thanks for the recommendation (link)!